# Is it possible to add a COM-Object to a Kubernetes container and if yes, how?

Tags: kubernetes, com, comobject

There is an old COM-Object that we need to use (no way around it) for an application that is planned to be in a Kubernetes container.
Is there any way to achieve this and if yes how?

I tried to research this, but with no results as of now.

Comment: Hi @Tai Kahar, I have been looking for your response whether the info shared by me was helpful to you. I am glad to assist you further if you have any additional queries or the issue still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add the COM-Object to the Kubernetes windows container only. COM is a technology that allows objects to interact across process and computer boundaries as easily as within a single process. COM enables this by specifying that the only way to manipulate the data associated with an object is through an interface on the object.

Since [COM Object Model](https://forums.docker.com/t/windows-application-32-bit-com-dll-registration/47205/6) is developed by Windows, You need to add the COM Object to the Windows container and add reference to the COM object using regsvr32. After creating a Dockerfile,

- Copy external DLLs into the container (the COM DLLs).
- Register the DLLs using regsvr32 in the container.
- Perform msbuild.

Refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-objects-and-interfaces) for more information on COM-Objects.